# Shake gesture and firstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get shake gesture to work. Here is some code

In my implementation file

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {

        NSLog(@"Shake gesture detected");

    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{ 
    return YES; 
}
```

I read that in order to make shake gesture to work UIView should be the firstResponder. This is why I added that code in implementation

```
if(self.view.isFirstResponder)
    {
        NSLog(@"first");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }

- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

When I run the app the output of NSLog is NO. What I miss ? And how to get shake gesture to work

Comment: Look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458616/shake-recognition-not-working-on-ios-4-does-work-on-ios-5 I implemented it the same way and it worked for me without the need to subclass something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're doing this in your UIViewController? That's not correct … You have to subclass UIView like this:

ShakeView.h:

```
//
//  ShakeView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShakeView : UIView {

}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder;

@end
```

ShakeView.m:

```
//
//  ShakeView.m
//

#import "ShakeView.h"

@implementation ShakeView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake ) {
    }    
    if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] ) {
        [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Then use ShakeView instead of your "normal" UIView and implement this in your UIViewController:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Shake happend …");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

That's it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: You mean to use myController : Shake instead of myController : UIViewController, right ?

Comment: No, you should use ShakeView instead of UIView. If you're using the Interface Builder go to your Storyboard / XIB, select your UIView, look on the right and find the "Identity inspector" then you can select a "Custom Class" (in our case it's the ShakeView).

Comment: I create my views programmatically. I have tried to subclass UIView instead UIViewController but I get an error. 
    self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
Property view not found on object of type 'questionViewController'

Comment: I think you should take a look at some basics about iOS development … If you dont use your ViewController with a XIB you should initialize your View in the loadView-methode and don't forget to import "ShakeView.h"

Comment: Well, here is what I did. I added ShakeView.h, ShakeView.m to my project with the code you suggest. Then in my ViewController.h I added ShakeView.h. In the implementation of ViewController I added motionEnded viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear methods. Shake recognition now working neither on simulator or device.

Comment: Well finally I get how to implement. Now it's work fine on iOS4 simulator but it doesn't on iOS5